# cheap and easy way to pass changing c++ strings between components of an application expecting char* parameters

Tags: c#, c++, visual-c++, c++98

I'm looking for a cheap and easy way to pass changing strings (similar to C#) between components of an app sitting on top of the framework expecting char* parameters in its API (written in C++98).

Something along the lines of:

```
char* get_filename (char* source_name ) {

  std::string fname = source_name;
  // switch source extension to .tmp
  fname = fname.substr(0, fname.rfind("."))+".TMP";

  return (char*) fname.c_str();
}

ret i = api_call( get_filename( "C:\TEMP\1.DAT") );
```

The above seems to be losing scope, so I'm curious if there's a cheap way to operate strings without buffers, strcpy, new and free, endlessly. Closest to the String of C# or Java, if this is possible in C++.

Comment: The `char *` being returned has to come from somewhere. Take your pick: either a fixed-size `char` buffer, or create it with `new` and `strcpy`. There are very few "cheap" things in C++. Everything beyond the most trivial tasks requires work.

Comment: @Sam, I was hoping std::string somehow addressed that

Comment: The whole purpose of `std::string` is that it ***manages the memory entirely by itself***, and `delete`s it when the string object gets destroyed. The purpose of a `std::string` is precisely the opposite of this.

Comment: `static`, maybe? Not sure that's a good option for what you're doing, but it's available to you.

Answer (score 1):

A function like `get_filename()`, as you currently have it defined, would only make sense if it just returns a pointer to the requested portion of the source data, without altering the data. IOW, if `get_filename("C:\\TEMP\\1.DAT")` returned a pointer to `"1.DAT"`, not allocates a new string `"1.TMP"`, eg.

```
char* get_filename (char* source_name )
{
    char *fname = strrchr(source_name, '\\');
    if (fname) {
        ++fname;
    }
    return fname;
}

ret i = api_call( get_filename( "C:\\TEMP\\1.DAT") );
```

But if you want that extra allocation/alteration, then you need to change your function to use `std::string` instead, eg:

```
std::string get_new_filename (const std::string &source_name)
{
    // switch source extension to .tmp
    std::string fname = source_name.substr(0, source_name.rfind(".")) + ".TMP";
    return fname;
}

ret i = api_call( get_new_filename("C:\\TEMP\\1.DAT").c_str() );
```

If the C API expects `char*` instead of `const char*`, there are a few different ways you can handle that:

```
// safe as long as api_call() doesn't try
// to alter the character data, only read it
std::string fname = get_new_filename("C:\\TEMP\\1.DAT");
ret i = api_call( const_cast<char*>(fname.c_str()) );
```

```
// guaranteed safe in C++11 or later, 
// *may* be safe in earlier versions,
// depending on library implementation
std::string fname = get_new_filename("C:\\TEMP\\1.DAT");
ret i = api_call( &fname[0] );
```

```
// requires C++17 or later, also guaranteed safe
std::string fname = get_new_filename("C:\\TEMP\\1.DAT");
ret i = api_call( fname.data() );
```